# Prove the following equality: $\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{4\cos(t)}\cos(4\sin(t))\;\mathrm{d}t = \pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

**Prove the following equality: 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{4\cos(t)}\cos(4\sin(t))\;\mathrm{d}t = \pi
$$**

Comment: What do you mean by "$c4\cos(t)$"? Are we dealing with plastic explosives?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Sorry that was a typo, I edited my post

Comment: Alright, by what method do you want to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure, It would be ideal for the proof to be very analytical (if that makes sense). Therefore, I think we should use euler's formula for cos and sin

Comment: expand $cos(4X)$ and put $cos(t)=u$.

Comment: Solving this using eulers formula and complex analysis  is pretty common. So common in fact that I've seen pretty much the exact same question multiple times in the last few weeks. I would recommend looking for similar questions... I don't have the time to do so myself atm, but I'm sure it won't be hard to find

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to see that the integral equals

$$\tag{$*$}\label{eq1}I=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{4e^{it}}+e^{4e^{-it}})\,dt.$$

The substitution $u=\pi-t$ yields

$$I=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{-4e^{iu}}+e^{-4e^{-iu}})\,du(\equiv\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{-4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{-it}})\,dt)$$

so

$$\begin{align}
2I&=I+I\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{4e^{it}}+e^{4e^{-it}})\,dt+\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{-4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{-it}})\,dt\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{4e^{it}}+e^{4e^{-it}}+e^{-4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{-it}})\,dt\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{it}}+e^{4e^{-it}}+e^{-4e^{-iu}})\,dt\\
&=\int_0^\pi \left(\frac12(e^{4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{it}})+\frac12(e^{4e^{-it}}+e^{-4e^{-it}})\right)\,dt\\
&=\int_0^\pi(\cosh(4e^{it})+\cosh(-4e^{it}))\,dt=2\int_0^\pi \cosh(4e^{it})\,dt
\end{align}$$

or

$$I=\int_0^\pi\cosh(4e^{it})\,dt.$$

Now let us define the function

$$\phi(x):=\int_0^\pi \cosh(xe^{it})\,dt.$$

Differentiation with respect to $x$ yields

$$\phi'(x)=\int_0^\pi e^{it}\sinh(xe^{it})\,dt
=-\left.\frac{i \cosh \left(e^{i t} x\right)}{x}\right]_0^\pi=0$$

so $\phi(x)$ is constant. This implies that

$$I=\phi(4)=\phi(0)=\int_0^\pi\cosh(0)\,dt=\pi.$$

**EDIT** (how to derive equation\eqref{eq1}):

$$\begin{align}
e^{4\cos(t)}\cos(4\sin(t))&=e^{4\cos(t)}\frac12(e^{i4\sin(t)}+e^{-i4\sin(t)})\\
&=
\frac12(e^{4(\cos(t)+i\sin(t))}+e^{4(\cos(t)-i\sin(t))})\\
&=\frac12(e^{4e^{it}}+e^{4e^{-it}})\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got $I=\int_0^\pi (e^{-4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{-it}})\,dt$ I used Euler's formula and wasn't able to find such an equality

Comment: I've added more details below, and corrected a typo

Comment: I understood how you derived the original equation. Now why do you perform a substitution $u=\pi - t$ and u does not appear in the integral? (sorry for my lack of understanding)

Comment: Ok sorry that's a second typo. I performed the substitution but didn't  change the name of the variable.

Comment: The substitution is $u=\pi-t$, $du=-dt$.

Comment: Yes, Brain fart here (sorry)

Comment: I'm Sorry but I don't understand how you get $I=\frac12\int_0^\pi (e^{-4e^{iu}}+e^{-4e^{-iu}})\,du =\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^\pi(\cos(4e^{it})+\cos(-4e^{it}))dt$

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: Nevermind, how can you say that $e^{4e^{it}} = e^{4e^{iu}}$? Don't we have $e^{4e^{iu}} = e^{4e^{i(\pi-t}} =e^{-4e^{it}}$?

Comment: The change of variable was performed in the second equation. After that $t$ and $u$ are nothing but "dummy" variables. I'll use the same one in all the equations if you feel more conformable that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47005/discussion-between-aribaldi-and-iqcd).

Comment: How does $\frac12(e^{4e^{it}}+e^{-4e^{it}}) = \cos(4e^{it})$?? I would think that this would be $\cosh(4e^{it})$ since there is no $i$ in the numerator

Comment: You are completely right. Fortunately the same reasoning works.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{4\cos t}\cos(4\sin t)$ is the real part of $e^{4\cos t}\cdot e^{4i\sin t}$, aka $\exp\left(4e^{it}\right)$. Since

$$ \exp\left(4 e^{it}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4^n e^{nit}}{n!} \tag{1}$$
and $\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{nit}\,dt$ equals either $0$ or a purely imaginary number for any $n\geq 1$,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{4\cos t}\cos(4\sin t)\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4^n}{n!}\text{Re}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{nit}\,dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}1\,dx = \color{red}{\pi},\tag{2}$$
i.e. only the contribute given by $n=0$ really matters.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Consider the other integral

$S=\int_0^\pi e^{4cos(t)}sin(4sin(t))dt$

and the sum

$C+iS=\int_0^\pi e^{4(cos(t)+isin(t))}dt$

$=\int_0^\pi e^{4e^{it}}dt$

put $4e^{it}=u$ or $t=-iln(u)+i2ln(2)$

the integral becomes

$i\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^udu}{u}$

I'll surely be downvoted.

Comment: So the real part is $\pi$ but the imaginary part is not elementary... So maybe this is harder than the original?