# Finding the Primitive of a Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Yesterday I saw the following post: [Prove the following equality: $\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{4\cos(t)}\cos(4\sin(t))\;\mathrm{d}t = \pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974347/prove-the-following-equality-int-0-pi-e4-cost-cos4-sint-mathr/1974494#1974417).

With a very interesting and complete answers

Now I was wondering If there was an analytical way to find a primitive of the function: 
$e^{4cos(t)}cos(4sin(t))dt$

Comment: Seems not. Maybe post used contour integrals...

Comment: @coffeemath is there a way to prove that there is no primitive for such a function?

Comment: Of course there is a primitive, since it is continuous.  But that primitive is not an elementary function.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you! Is there a way to find the primitive analytically and is it possible to prove that the primitive is not an elementary function?

Comment: User380438 There are methods to show certain functions do not have elementary primitives. Try a google on "elementary primitives" or the like--- shouldn't take much search to get a hit or two about this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonelementary_integral was the first "hit" I got, but it was for "nonelementary antiderivitive" as the google lookup. That article has some of the ones known not to have elementary antiderivatives, e.g. $sin(x^2).$

Comment: @coffeemath Can sin and  cos be seen as rationnal functions?

Comment: sin and cos are are among the so-called "elementary functions". they are not "rati9onal functions" which are also considered elementary, along with $e^x$ and a few others. I suggest you look at the wiki page I linked to in my other comment above for some definitions of "elementary functions" etc.

Comment: @coffeemath What if you make the substitution $tan(x/2) \rightarrow t$?

Comment: user 380438 Why not try that, and put the result in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Maple does it in terms of the exponential integral function $\mathrm{Ei}_1$.
$$
\int \!{{\rm e}^{4\,\cos \left( t \right) }}\cos \left( 4\,\sin
 \left( t \right)  \right) \,{\rm d}t
=
\frac{i}{2} \left( {\rm Ei}_1 \left( -4\,{{\rm e}^{it}} \right) -{\rm Ei}_1
 \left( -4\,{{\rm e}^{-it}} \right)  \right)
$$

Definition for this non-elementary function...
$$
\mathrm{Ei}_1(z) = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-sz}}{s}\,ds,\qquad
\mathrm{Re}\;z > 0
$$
and analytic continuation for other $z$ except $z=0$.

**edit**
How can we prove a function is not elementary?  An easy start (with many references):

"Integration in Finite Terms", Maxwell Rosenlicht,
*The American Mathematical Monthly* **79** (1972) 963--972.
Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2318066

Comment: Is it possible to find such a primitive analytically?